# How to find a Excel cell has hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in Column A in excel..I am iterating through column and i need to find if a cell value has hyperlink init.

```
LR=Activeworkbook.Worksheets("Emp").Range("A65000").End(xlup).Row
for j=1 to LR
  if Thisworkbooks.Worksheets("Emp").cells(j,1)="" then 'Logic to find hyperlink
    'Function 
  end if
```

next

Comment: Something like
`If Thisworkbooks.Worksheets("Emp").cells(j,1).Hyperlinks.Count` >0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Identify Cells Containing Hyperlinks

- As Red Hare already mentioned in the comments, it is best tested with something like the following:

  ```
  Dim cell As Range: Set cell = Sheet1.Range("A1")
  If cell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then ' has a hyperlink
  Else ' has no hyperlink
  End If
  ```

  that is, using the [`Hyperlinks.Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlinks.count) property of the [`Hyperlinks object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlinks)  returned by the cell's [`Hyperlinks property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.hyperlinks) which is a collection of hyperlinks in a range (in this case, a single cell). For a single cell, the Count property will return only 0 or 1 so you could actually use

  ```
  If cell.Hyperlinks.Count = 1 Then ' has a hyperlink
  ```

  instead.

**Example Code**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub IdentifyCellsWithHyperlink()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If it's not, modify accordingly.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Emp")
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim cell As Range
    
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        If cell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then ' has a hyperlink
        
        Else ' has no hyperlink
        
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that can be used to run through each row to determine if it can be set as a hyperlink. Kinda hard to figure out what the range of possible solutions are that will work for you without fully understanding the context...

```
Private Sub cmdFollowLink_Click()
```

CreateHyperlink Me!cmdFollowLink, Me!txtSubAddress, _
Me!txtAddress
End Sub

Sub CreateHyperlink(ctlSelected As Control, _
strSubAddress As String, Optional strAddress As String)
Dim hlk As Hyperlink
Select Case ctlSelected.ControlType
Case acLabel, acImage, acCommandButton
Set hlk = ctlSelected.Hyperlink
With hlk
If Not IsMissing(strAddress) Then
.Address = strAddress
Else
.Address = ""
End If
.SubAddress = strSubAddress
.Follow
.Address = ""
.SubAddress = ""
End With
Case Else
MsgBox "The control '" & ctlSelected.Name _
& "' does not support hyperlinks."
End Select
End Sub

Comment: Hello Troy,I am trying to find the cells  have link...I am not trying to set any cells into hyperlink